# Postgresql select columns based on json column

Tags: postgresql, json, merge

Thanks in advance.

```
table-1
| ID | name | json |
| 1  | jack | {color: 'red', size: 'large' } |


table-2
| ID | color | size | qty |
| 1  | black | small|  10 |
```

If json is not null result

```
| ID | name | color | size  | qty |
| 1  | jack | black | small | 10 |
```

If json is null

```
| ID | name | qty |
| 1  | jack | 10  |
```

Table 1 will join Table 2.  If json is not null need to select all keys from json as columns on table 2 otherwise if json is null we don't select them.  Just can't quite figure out the json part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, add a minimum table schema, and the desired result.

Comment: I've updated to include the schema, but we do not know what you're talking about still @keither78. Do you mean to type the columns of table2, or do you want that automatic (which would require dynamic sql), and be substantially harder..?

Comment: I edited it to hopefully clear it up a bit? haha.  Thank y'all for the quick responses.

Comment: How do you know what keys to not-select if JSON is null. Look at your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id, jsondata)
AS
  VALUES ( 1, $${"foo":"no", "bar":"go"}$$::jsonb );

CREATE TABLE table2(id, foo, bar)
AS
  VALUES ( 1, 'yes', 'no' );
```

Just use coalesce

```
SELECT t1.id,
  coalesce(jsondata->>'foo', t2.foo) AS foo,
  coalesce(jsondata->>'bar', t2.bar) AS bar
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
  USING (id);
```

Also, when someone updates your question to CTAS and schema, you should keep it and not go back to a textual grid.

Comment: i didn't see it.. sorry about that

Comment: I disagree: the "textual grid" is a much better representation of sample data. A CTAS or plain insert statements might be supplied additionally.